# Synchronize folders using C

Tags: c, file, directory, synchronization

I want to synchronize the contents of two folders using C. I don't have any line of code, I simple want someone to suggest a good tutorial to start with.

Comment: Any reason you need to use C?  I would suggest that a shell or batch scripting language might be better for this task.

Comment: I agree with you, but I want to do it using C. I want to create a kind of "database", e.g. list all files in a text file and then sync them.

Comment: Unless there is a reason to roll your own I'd suggest adopting an existing solution. One example of which would be rsync (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), free versions of which are available for various platforms.

Comment: You might want to add more to your question. Assuming this is a learning project (you don't want to just use rsync or ), it'd be helpful for you to provide more information about where you're having problems. How to read the filesystem? How to intelligently build your database?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no 'C' way to do this.  You will need to use platform-dependent filesystem functions.  What OS are you running?

On Linux systems, try [`opendir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and friends (from dirent.h).

On Windows systems, try [this listing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of Win32 File Management functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about `dirent.h` and `stat`. Googling for those I found [this link](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/111717-how-use-part-dirent-h.html).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not writing code, but using [Sync Butler](http://syncbutler.org/).

Otherwise you may want to search the Boost library for any platform independent methods for accessing folders (since you didn't tell us which OS or platform you are using).